# Why is the time complexity of this code O(N)?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I thought the time complexity of the code below is O(n^2) or O(n*logn).

```
int j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
        j++;
    }
}
```

However, the answer page says it is O(n).
I can't understand why it becomes so.
My (silly) opinions were the following:

1. The time complexity is O(n^2) since there are two loop running `n` times. `arr[i] < arr[j]` may affect the `while` loop, but it doesn't matter.
2. The time complexity is O(n*logn) since the while loop may run less than `n` times because `arr[j]` can be smaller than `arr[i]` during the loop. As a result, `while` loop would run for `log(n)` times.

Could you explain why was my answer wrong and why the correct time complexity is O(n)?

Comment: Note that j is newer reset to 0. So the inner loop can only run O(n) times in total

Comment: The inner loop will run only once as you don't reinititialize j to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

Loops `n` times.

```
while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
    j++;
}
```

Loops up to `n` times **in total**. Note that `j` is only ever incrementing for the entire loop of `i`, so it being an inner loop doesn't make it a higher order, as it still can only go from `0` to `n` for the entire set of loops.

So it's `O(2n)` = `O(n)`

Comment: Now understood... Once j has reached n, it isn't reset to 0, so that while loop won't run any longer.

Comment: Yep, or even if it never reaches `n`, it's still never reset, so it can never go further than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to understand the flow of something like this, try adding print statements to understand the flow, printing 'i' and 'j' at every point.

In this specific case, you know how many times the outer `for` loop is triggered, but try to see how many total times `j` can be incremented. Even though it's inside the `for` loop, its number of total iterations may be independent.